# How to copy a content to Clipboard in pure Dart?

Tags: dart, dart-pub

I would like to copy a Text to Clipboard in a Dart console App.

There is this plugin [clipboard_manager](https://pub.dev/packages/clipboard_manager#-readme-tab-) but it is specific to flutter. 
Is there any way to do this in pure Dart?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [clippy](https://pub.dev/packages/clippy) dart package provides clipboard access for dart. It uses different mechanisms depending on whether you're on Linux, Mac, and Windows, but provides a simple dart API to copy and also to listen to pastes.

You might look at the [server example script](https://github.com/andresaraujo/clippy/blob/master/example/server/main.dart), which works for a console application too.

Comment: it works. i had to install a external lib in linux, but it is not a big deal. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by importing `import 'package:flutter/services.dart';`
and then by using the following snippet `Clipboard.setData(ClipboardData(text: 'ToTheMoon123456'));`
**No package required!

Comment: This is not **pure** dart. You're importing flutter packages.

Comment: This will not work in a Dart CLI script. `flutter/services.dart` imports `dart:ui`, which is not available on the command line.